# Merging two columns in Crystal reports into one

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Report Development. I have a dataset with a datatable holding values from various tables in my database. For single valued columns, I face no problem and they successfully show on the report.  Here, is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT Product.Image, Product.Model_No, Order_Detail.Quantity, Product.Title, Order_Detail.Selected_Warehouse, Order_Header.Order_No, Order_Header.Order_Date, " +
                        "Order_Shipping_Detail.Collector_Name, " +
                        "Order_Shipping_Detail.Address_Line + Order_Shipping_Detail.Collector_Number AS shipping " +
                        "FROM " +
                    "Order_Detail INNER JOIN Order_Header ON Order_Detail.Order_Id = Order_Header.Id INNER JOIN Product ON Order_Detail.Order_Product_Id=Product.Id " +
                    "INNER JOIN Order_Shipping_Detail ON Order_Detail.Order_Id = Order_Shipping_Detail.Order_Id " +
                    "WHERE Status=@Status AND Selected_Warehouse=@Selected_Warehouse
```

The last part

```
Order_Shipping_Detail.Address_Line + Order_Shipping_Detail.Collector_Number AS shipping
```

is a concatenation of two fields. However, I'm failing to understand how to show them together under a single header. Which field do I add in crystal reports to make it work.

Comment: 1. If `Collector_Number` is numeric you need to convert it like `CONVERT(varchar(10), Order_Shipping_Detail.Collector_Number)`  - 2. In your report  you can also use formula field to concatenate them and use it in one column ;).

Comment: thank you for you reply. I was able to figure it out. It was staring me right down at my face.
{DataTable1.Collector_Name} & {DataTable1.Address_Line}